# Trust Settings MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to programmatically disable ENABLE CONTENT Security message bar. I have a spreadsheet with some macros and some forms, however, even though i save the spreadsheet with the Trust Settings set to NEVER SHOW INFORMATION ABOUT BLOCKING SECURITY, it still pops up if i send the spreadsheet to someone else to open. I'm try to permanently disable it, or add some code to THISWORKBOOK_OPEN so that whenever it opens, it never prompts the user to click the ENABLE CONTENT button

Edit the problem i have is that i have a form tha is supposed to appear before users are able to use the spreadshet but in this case when they open it they firsy havento click enable content before the log in form appears .....is there a waynaround it?

Comment: think about it: if you can just enable a flag in the .xls that says "I'm trustworthy, let me do whatever I want without any warnings to the user", don't you think virus writers would be all over that? Unless the spreadsheet's digitally signed, and the user TRUSTS that signature, their Excel will always pop up the warning.

Comment: It's not quite what you want but if you had a digital signature and your users trusted that signature they wouldn't get the pop-up after that.

Comment: whats with all these downvotes. people relax

Answer (score 2):

No. Definitely Not. Never. Ever.

Comment: I'm opening a user form when workbook opens. with enable content, user first has to click on that before the login forms pops up. it kind of defeats the purpose is there a way to stop it from doing that, at least have it appear after the login was successful. what i'm doing is creating an empty sheet with user login form, then after successful login the extra sheet gets deleted. In this case, the sheet doesn't get created, user has to enable content (while seeing the content of tab) and then sheet gets created and log in form comes up

Comment: The whole point of the "Enable content" button is to stop malicious code from untrustworthy sources running on your computer. Anyone could send anything to anyone. It's up to the receiver to decide whether they trust the sender or not, you can't just tell another computer to "Do whatever I like" without the user of the other computer first saying "Let this person do whatever they like". There is NO way around it and there should never ever be!

Comment: You see my purpose in this right? I understand the security content, this is a spreadsheet that will be passed around internally, from a network drive to users computers.

Comment: @Bobski Then get yourself a self-signed certificate, get everyone on the local network to install and trust it, and sign your macro with it.